# OLE alternatives\workaround for .net

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ole, te-edit

We plan to migrate a desktop application which was build using MFC\C++ to WPF. One of the control used is a Rich Text Editor [TE Edit](http://www.subsystems.com/tewf.htm).

This rich text box supports embedding of OLE objects. This implies things such as MS Office documents can be linked in the textbox. Such items when clicked open the designated application where one can change the content and the content is updated in the text box itself.

Can we support this in .net? Are there any workarounds to support such scenarios? From what I understand OLE is deal and not supported by the framework. But the use case seems to be valid one and an alternative should be presented to the client.

Comment: check MS Forum and links provided: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/fb06400b-8781-44a3-abda-4be872e655c9

Comment: OLE is dead as a doornail.  .NET has no support for it at all.  You'll need to keep your MFC project alive and rely on ActiveX support in .NET to host it.